# What technology is Microsoft recommending to replace Microsoft Sync Framework?

Tags: windows-ce, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-ce-4, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have an project where I want to scan data to a table using a handheld device.  The device would be docked sending the batch of data to the PC to be processed using *ActiveSync* or *Windows Mobile Device Center*. The device in this case runs *Windows CE 6.0*.

The customer has an existing app that uses *PocketAccess* to do this, but that support was removed many years ago in CE, so it limits his access to new devices.

I first started looking at alternatives and saw a lot about *Microsoft Sync Framework*. But I have since discovered that it is no longer supported in *SQL Compact 4.0*.

So rather than design something that is already obsolete, what should I be looking at?

Comment: I hate to be unhelpful, but the whole OS is obsolete. Even Microsoft has removed most support for it. If you're developing for an obsolete OS, you should expect to have to use obsolete libraries and tools.

Comment: @PaulH Not unhelpful at all. It's just that the mobile scanner market is very fractured and new machines with older OS are still sold and bought by customers. Trying to get a good map of the land is really hard. If there is overlap I want to go with something current. If not, then so be it.